# Small Basic new line code

Tags: newline, smallbasic

The problem is: Whenever you type in 2 numbers, as required, the results are lined one after another, what creates an image of a huge number. Does anyone know a code/command to separate the results of  arithmetic operations into rows? Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Share with us what you've tried so far. We're happy to help, but this is not a free programming service!

Comment: To be honest, I have tried array["e.g."][1][1] = "e.g." and tried with \r\n, but it did not work. Basic is a programming language I require to work in for the graduation work, but today is the first time I even opened it.

Comment: MADE IT WORK!! Used Returned Value = Text Window. Read Number() under every variable and it worked! Thanks anyway, @thickguru

Comment: That's great. Add it as an answer so it can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Between writing out the two numbers you can add TextWindow.WriteLine() that will but the cursor on to the next row so the second number will be written out below.